# plain javascript: overlay object

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, overlay

There is any object (could be an inline object like  but also a block element like  or ) as original object.

Now I try to set an overlay  over this object, with the same position and size.

=> `function overlayObject(originalObject)`

Creating the new overlay  and mirroring the size of the original object works well. I can also append this new element within the originalObject's parent node.

Regarding the position, left+top for achieving the overlay, is still pending and failing. With original objects that have position:absolute or position:fixed, it's easy, but how to get the exact left/top position to use the same with the overlay ?

Comment: Just to clarify a little — where you say “any object”, do you mean “any element”?

Comment: yes, element in the html body.

Comment: So is your question “how can I find the coordinates of an element relative to the entire document”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` to determine the top and left distance of your element to the parent element:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpAxX/5/)

```
function createOverlay(el) {
    var t = el.offsetTop;
    var l = el.offsetLeft;
    var newEl = el.cloneNode(true);
    newEl.style.margin = "0";
    newEl.style.position = "absolute";
    newEl.style.left = l + "px";
    newEl.style.top = t + "px";
    newEl.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,255,0.3)";
    el.offestParent.appendChild(newEl);
}
```

Comment: Note that it’ll be the distance to the offset parent, which is slightly different. Luckily, you can just use `offsetParent` instead of `parentNode`.